# gerrit sendemail "Server rejected body"

Tags: email, smtp, gerrit

After I configured my gerrit server with our SMTP server, I can not send email, can anyone help?

I was trying to config my gerrit with SMTP server, after I checked with command "gsasl --smtp -a  --connect=10.4.103.110:25 -p passwrod", I have confirmed that my connection with SMTP server is correct.

After I configured it into gerrit.config, and restart gerrit. I tried to modify my first account's contact information by the webUI, I met a problem like "server xxxx rejected body".
Then I checked with log, and found the line is at 204 in the file "SmtpEmailSender.java", the code is like :

```
w = new BufferedWriter(w);

for (Map.Entry<String, EmailHeader> h : hdrs.entrySet()) {
  if (!h.getValue().isEmpty()) {
     w.write(h.getKey());
     w.write(": ");
     h.getValue().write(w);
     w.write("\r\n");
  }
}

w.write("\r\n");
w.write(body);
w.flush();
w.close();

if (!client.completePendingCommand()) {
   throw new EmailException("Server " + smtpHost + " rejected body");
}
```

Comment: As I do not understand those java code, I have no idea how to resolve it, I have searched internet for several days, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem is because I tried to display my email address as a non-relative address.

My address was aaa@mymail.com, I tried to config the user as bbb@mymail.com, the SMTP server rejected my send email request.